# R to connect to github API but an credentials error

Tags: r, api

```
library(httr)
library(httpuv)
library(jsonlite)
myapi <- oauth_app("github", "0b23485d6d6e55143372", 
                   secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"), myapi)
request1 <- GET("https://api.github.com/users/jtleek/repos", config(token = github_token))
myjson <- content(request1)
myjson2 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(myjson))
View(myjson2)
stop_for_status(request1)
```

#

I use R 3.2.5 and Win7 32 bit.
There are 2 problems. One is after the final line of code, I got an error **Error: Unauthorized (HTTP 401).**

```
And the second is when I tried to see what the github_token is, 
<Token>
<credentials> error, error_description, error_uri
```

#

Finally **myjson2** is not a dataframe but just a list

```
$message
[1] "Bad credentials"

$documentation_url
[1] "https://developer.github.com/v3"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, so I have created a new set of key and secret on github page. By the way, I don't think you need to convert using jsonlite::, the format should be fine. I used the following:

```
gtoken <- config(token = github_token)
req <- with_config(gtoken, GET("https://api.github.com/users/jtleek/repos"))
con_req <- content(req)

find_create <- function(x,myurl) {
  if (x$html_url == myurl) {
    print(x$created_at)
  }
}

lapply(con_req,find_create,myurl ="https://github.com/jtleek/datasharing")
```